# Hide iPad apps under password

Tags: ios, ipad, passwords, hide

Is there any way to hide all the iPad apps (but one) or restrict them under some password?
We need to have iPads that can only use one app.

P.S. It would be legal, without using cydia or something like that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this. I think you are looking for kiosk mode.

But in iOS 6 there is one option in Settings App called [Guided Access](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509) for doing this.

Check this tutorial for [Kiosk](http://www.imore.com/how-enable-guided-access-iphone-and-ipad) mode.

Comment: this is not what i was looking for but for now is the best solution THANKS!

Comment: @javiazo: You can't do this via code on non-jailbreak devices. Anyway thanks for your comment :)

Comment: really I didn't want do it via code, this is for prepare some iPads to be used with only one application, actually I will use your option